# Show fragment in Viewpager without tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have 3 tabs with 3 different fragments..
I want to show fourth fragment in ViewPager but i don't want to create a new TAB for that..

How is it possible to show fragment in viewPager without creating a new TabLayout item?

In my mainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /* CONTENT */
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Toolbar
    Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(tb);

    //Tabs
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_map));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_add_white_48dp));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
        if (tab != null) tab.setCustomView(R.layout.view_tabs);
    }

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            currentTab = tab.getPosition();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

    });

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Log.v("Main", "Onpageselected");
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });


}
```

And I don't know, what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

So the forth Fragment going to be Tabless?
You can try adding `Tabs` to `TabLayout` manually using `tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"))` instead of using `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mPager)`, this way you can set only the Tabs you need and the rest of fragments are going to be Tabless.
Also don't forget you need to set `setOnTabSelectedListener(OnTabSelectedListener)` and `setOnPageChangeListener`  or `addOnPageChangeListener` too.

Comment: Thanks. Yes. Fourth Fragment needs to be tabless. I edited my post and add there a current code.